# image_view symbol lookup error

Tags: usb-cam, image-view, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

Whenever I try to use image_view to visualize a topic published by usb_cam with the following command:

```
rosrun image_view image_view image:=/usb_cam/image_raw
```

I get this:

```
init done 
opengl support available 
[ INFO] [1457614339.953957839]: Using transport "compressed"
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/image_view/image_view: symbol lookup error: /opt/ros/indigo/lib/image_view/image_view: undefined symbol: _ZN9cv_bridge18cvtColorForDisplayERKN5boost10shared_ptrIKNS_7CvImageEEERKSsbdd
```

The same happens even with the "raw" transport:

```
init done 
opengl support available 
[ INFO] [1457614438.464431134]: Using transport "raw"
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/image_view/image_view: symbol lookup error: /opt/ros/indigo/lib/image_view/image_view: undefined symbol: _ZN9cv_bridge18cvtColorForDisplayERKN5boost10shared_ptrIKNS_7CvImageEEERKSsbdd
```

Am I doing something wrong? has anyone got similar errors?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228693/image_view-symbol-lookup-error/) by [nvoltex](https://answers.ros.org/users/3575/nvoltex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2016-03-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2016-03-10**:
Please provide more information. What commands do you run so that these errors occur?

**Comment by [nvoltex](https://answers.ros.org/users/3575/nvoltex/) on 2016-03-10**:
You are right, I'm sorry I forgot to add the command. Thanks for warning me.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-03-11**:
this seems to point to a problem with linking. Did you install 'image_view'  from source or via 'apt-get'? Which OS/ROS-Distro?
Maybe also check if [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/121266/undefined-symbol/) helps...

**Comment by [hafager](https://answers.ros.org/users/27678/hafager/) on 2016-08-04**:
If you installed via apt-get, you might have to source setup.bash.

```
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
```

**Comment by [huisen liu](https://answers.ros.org/users/27698/huisen-liu/) on 2016-09-10**:
@nvoltex Have you solved this problem?I met the same recently,I tried the other methods suggested by others,but all didn't work.

**Comment by [grmarcil](https://answers.ros.org/users/30086/grmarcil/) on 2017-04-19**:
In addition to Ziwen Qin's suggestion, I needed to run `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-cv-bridge`. Versions of cv-bridge lower than 1.11.13 appear to cause this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This appears to be a bug with ROS' apt-get image-view program (version 1.12.18): https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline/issues/215

I'd recommend running
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-image-view

to pull down the latest fixed package.

---

Originally posted by [Ziwen Qin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26914/ziwen-qin/) with karma: 136 on 2016-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0